# Power series with inverses of primes as coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, power-series

I was thinking about the power series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  {{x^n}\over{p_{n+1}}} $
where $p_{n+1}$ is the ${n+1}^{th}$ prime number. It should converge $\forall x\in [-1,1)$ ,
but to which number? Is it rational, algebraic, transcendental? Is it even possible to determine the sum? As a comment pointed out, the series for x=-1 already has been analyzed. (A078437)
Though what about the values x=0.5, or x=-0.5? is there an explicit formula, maybe in terms of other constants?

Comment: Digits of alternating series ($x=-1$) is [A078437](https://oeis.org/A078437), apparently it's not even known what the $15$-th digit is (it's conjectured to be $4$) ...

Comment: What's $p_0$? Shouldn't the sum start at $1$?

Comment: The behaviour for $x\to1^-$ should be roughly $\log\log\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)$, since $p_n\sim n\log n$, $\int\frac{\mathrm dn}{n\log n}=\log\log n$ and the factor $x^n$ kicks in around $n=\frac1{1-x}$.

Comment: @joriki using the OEIS definition for primes, I think it would make more sense for the series to start with $ p_0 = 2 $

Comment: @OscarBizard: Which definition are you referring to? In [OEIS sequence A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040), the offset is specified as $1$, which unless I'm completely mistaken means that the first number listed, $2$, has index $1$. (Perhaps there was a misunderstanding – I didn't mean that the sum should start with the value $p_n=1$ but with the index $n=1$.)

Comment: @joriki my bad, I just corrected the question.